# What does binascii.hexlify(os.urandom(32)).decode() mean?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, auth-token, binascii

I'm trying to develop a function which would refresh `token` model in django rest framework.They seem to use `binascii.hexlify(os.urandom(32)).decode()` for generating unique tokens for every user.How does this line ensures that token generated by it will always be unique.Suppose if i want to refresh content of token after every 10 months ,then, will `binascii.hexlify(os.urandom(32)).decode()` will generate unique key that has not been used by any current user or i need to check whether it is being used or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`help(os.urandom)` says:

> Return a bytes object containing random bytes suitable for cryptographic use.

On Linux this will use the `/dev/urandom` character device which is designed to be cryptographically secure. Only time it could fail to generate so would be the very early stage of boot when the entropy pool is not initialized yet <sup>1</sup>. But once it's initialized and seeded from the previouse seed, device drives and so on you would generate cryptographic grade randomness.

Also check `man 4 urandom`.

<sup>1</sup> `getrandom(2)` system call is there for these cases, which is blocking  unlike reading from `/dev/urandom`.

---

`binascii.hexlify(os.urandom(32)).decode()`:

- `os.urandom(32)` returns 32 bytes of random data
- `binascii.hexlify` returns the hex represntation of the bytes
- as the return from `hexlify` is bytes we need to `decode` it to get string

So as the original random bytes are being retrieved from `os.urandom` this should be (cryptographically) secure randomness.

Comment: Okay so if i need to change its content after some time using same statement, will it still generate a unique key

Comment: @GaganSingh Yes.

Comment: i know about accepting, sorry for being late and thanks for explanation